# Why is "NOT(table_name IS NOT NULL)" not equal to "table_name IS NULL"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-cleaning

I'm currently in an online SQL course.

In this module:

1. I'm tasked to identify all the null rows in the data set.
2. After identifying, perform data cleaning by populating the null.

**Answer key**: This code returns a list of all null items/rows.

```
SELECT * FROM cprodsales2
WHERE NOT(cprodsales2 IS NOT NULL)
;
```

**What I've tried**: This code returns nothing. Blank.

```
SELECT * FROM cprodsales2
WHERE cprodsales2 IS NULL
;
```

I'm quite confused why both code won't return the same result.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/uI7k9EH2, i.e. same result.

Comment: That behavior is easily reproducible, so the question should be reopened.

Comment: The query is wrong. It's using the *table name* in the `IS NULL` condition. Other databases would throw a syntax error. PostgreSQL will match a row where all columns are NULL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have fixed the title.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What if the table has a column with the same name? i.e. `cprodsales2.cprodsales2` ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing a whole row, and composite expressions behave strangely with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT (1, NULL) IS NULL;

 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)

SELECT NOT ((1, NULL) IS NOT NULL);

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

This is required by the SQL standard. NULL and composite types are just weird.

A row type `IS NULL` if all components are NULL. It `IS NOT NULL` if all its components are not NULL. Anything else is neither NULL nor NOT NULL.

So `WHERE NOT(cprodsales2 IS NOT NULL)` will pass only those table rows for which at least one column has a NULL value.

Comment: That's not unexpected. A `(1,NULL)` isn't a missing value. It's a value with a missing part. The really weird part is that `SELECT (1, NULL) IS NOT NULL` is `f`.

Comment: The OP's code is using the *table name* in the `WHERE` clause: `cprodsales2 IS NULL`

Comment: Ah, that explains it, thanks.

Comment: Why does this syntax even exist? I don't think any other database allows this.

Comment: [From this](https://dbfiddle.uk/MSOq6-3w) it seems that `table IS NOT NULL` returns all rows that have no nulls at all (already breaking null logic), so `NOT ( table IS NOT NULL)` returns the rows that have at least one NULL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Every database that conforms to the SQL standard must behave like that.

Comment: The other databases in dbFiddle don't allow `tableName IS NULL`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `tablename is null` seems to be Postgresql specific, i.e. not SQL standard.

Comment: @jarlh Not sure, but `ROW(tablename.*) IS NULL` might me more standard-conforming.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I can't see that should be valid. (However, I can be wrong, the ISO 9075 spec takes ages to read. )

Comment: @jarlh Foundation, chapter 7.1 "row value constructor".

Comment: Yes, but which way to go to reach `ROW(tablename.*)`?

Comment: @jarlh Huh? I gave you chapter and verse from the SQL standard.

Comment: Yes, but I can only find <qualified asterisk> in 7.16 <query specification>. And the row value constructor doesn't seem to include <query specification>.

Comment: Hi beautiful human beings, thanks for helping out. I'll try to process everything you guys just said. This is quite to take for a beginner haha. 

Have a great day ahead!

Comment: @jarlh This is getting somewhat off-topic, but a <row value constructor> can contain a <common value expression>, which can be a <reference value expression>, which is a <value expression primary>, which can be a <nonparenthesized value expression primary>, which can be a <column reference>. You are right that the standard mentions `*` only directly in the `SELECT` list, but at least the PostgreSQL syntax does not extend the standard in an unnatural way. By the way, the standard seems to have no provision for syntax like `SELECT *, row_number OVER ()`.